# RecyclerView data are multiple modified/displayed

Tags: android, adapter, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I've a small problem with my RecyclerView. It's well filled by my adapter with some TextViews, an ImageView and some buttons. When there's an OnClick-Event on one of the buttons it modifies a TextView - so far so good but when I'm scrolling some items further another RecyclerView-item is also modified and has the value of the originally modified one.

I tried already to move the setOnClickListener into my ViewHolder but the result was the same.

May be you can help me.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    // some vars .... and a constructor

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        // ...

        viewHolder.myTextView.setText("clear");
        viewHolder.myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewHolder.myTextView.setText("modified");
            }
        });

        // ...
    }

    @Override
      public int getItemCount() {
        return mProducts.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView productMultibuy;
        private Button productAddToShoppingList;

        // ...
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
            myButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);

            // ...


            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                }
            });


            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks, but I solved the problem with setTag() and getTag()

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
// some vars .... and a constructor

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_item, viewGroup, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    // ...
}

@Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return mProducts.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView productMultibuy;
    private Button productAddToShoppingList;

    // ...
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        myTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
        myTextView.setTag(this);
        myButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_button);
        myButton.setTag(this);

        // ...

        myButton.getTag();
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    myTextView.getTag();
                    myTextView.setText(String.valueOf(amount));
                }
            }
        });


    }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Reading from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580478/cant-get-recyclerview-adapter-to-properly-display).

RecyclerView, just the same as ListView and GridView, reuses views whenever possible. That means while you scroll, views that fall off the top are used for the views on the bottom, etc. This greatly improves the memory efficiency and scroll performance. This means if you don't reset all of the state on a new item, you'll see state left over from the last time this view was used.

> always reset all the of the state